# How to calculate the sum of all the odd numbers less than 1000 using a for loop in Xcode (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to programming and I have no idea where to start, just looking for some help with this, I know its very simple but I'm clueless, thanks for the help!

So this is the code I have:

```
NSInteger sum = 0;
for (int a = 1; a < 500; a++) {
    sum += (a * 2 - 1); }
NSLog(@"The sum of all the odd numbers within the range = %ld",(long)sum);
```

but I'm getting a answer of 249,001, but it should be 250,000

Appreciate the help!

Comment: "I have no idea where to start" ... Start with `for` loop. Then change it to jump by 2 every time. Then sum those values. You have to give it a modicum of effort.

Comment: `NSInteger sum = 0; for (int $ = 1; $ < 500; $++) { sum += ($ * 2 - 1); }`

Comment: Thank you helped a lot! but can you just view the code i just edited into my question and explain whats wrong, thank you @holex

Comment: @holex - Given your algorithm, you need `<= 500`, not `< 500`. Personally, I'd be inclined to do `for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i += 2) { sum += i }`...

Comment: @Rob, indeed... thank for the correction.

Answer (score -2):

Your immediate problem is that you're missing a term in the sum: your output differs from the actual answer by 999. This ought to motivate you to write `a <= 500` instead as the stopping condition in the `for` loop.

But, in reality, you would **not** use a `for` loop for this as there is an alternative that's much cheaper computationally speaking.

Note that this is an *arithmetic progression* and there is therefore a *closed-form* solution to this. That is, you can get the answer out in O(1) rather than by using a loop which would be O(n); i.e. the compute time grows linearly with the number of terms that you want.

Recognising that there are 500 odd numbers in your range, you can use

`n * (2 * a  + (n - 1) * d) / 2`

to compute this. In your case, `n` is 500. `d` (the difference between the terms) is 2. `a` (the first term) is 1.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: The question was quite specific, asking how to do this with a `for` loop. I suspect that this is an assignment designed to teach the basics of `for` loops. To suggest that he doesn't use a `for` loop somewhat defeats that purpose.

Comment: Understood. I've amended, respecting this as a good reason to downvote although I'd love to have a robust conversation with the lecturer who picked this as the example. You should *always* look out for closed form solutions.

Comment: @Bathsheba This is actually a very good assignment, especially because there is a closed-form solution you can use to verify your results. There are multiple similar algorithms in the books that can be used for learning purposes but have no practical value (e.g. Sieve of Eratosthenes).